# SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory not available with Hibernate 6.1.7

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, ehcache-3, hibernate-6.x

We are using hibernate 5.2.5, where we were overriding **start** method of `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` todo some init actions. This class
we configure in **persistence.xml** for key "**hibernate.cache.region.factory_class**"

```
public class AppSingletonEhCacheRegionFactory extends SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory {

    @Override
    public void start(SessionFactoryOptions settings, Properties properties) throws CacheException {
        //init_actions
        super.start(settings, properties);
    }
}
```

Now we are upgrading to 6.1.7.FINAL

In docs, EHcache is not mentioned in hibernate 6.1.7 https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-config-provider

*persistence.xml*

```
 <persistence-unit name="db" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>app.jdbc.APPDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:main"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                      value="com.app.AppSingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30"/>
            <property name="net.sf.ehcache.cacheManagerName" value="app-cache"/>
            <property name="hibernate.integration.envers.enabled" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

EHcache can be configure by using the JCache integration. Take a look into the [JCache integration tests](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/main/hibernate-jcache/src/test) to see how we test this.